# PHP NO CARGA COMPLETO SIEMPRE

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, ejecuto un modulo de mi sistema y la mayoría de las veces me carga una tabla con todos sus registros.

3 de 10 veces no termina de cargar la tabla, esto me sucede en varias áreas del sistema y no logro encontrar el problema.

Probé ampliar el tiempo de ejecución, verifique en los logs de nginx y no encontré nada, no se que mas probar.

No es el fuente ya que compila bien y me pasa en diferentes modulos lo mismo.

Comment: Puede ser un problema de tu red, la base de datos, o miles de otras cosas. sin mas informacion va a ser dificil ayudarte.

Comment: conclusion: probablemente tu servidor apache2/nginx debes ampliar el timeout, te recomiendo que busques como hacer eso en el servidor que estas trabajabndo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes revisar el archivo php.ini y modificar los valores siguientes.
En especial la ultima parte que hace referencia a la memoria, tal vez tus rutinas ocupen demasiada memoria y agoten la reservada por php.
Prueba y nos dices si te funciono.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time=30

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time=60

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
; max_input_vars = 1000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=128M
```

Comment: parece que era el memory_limt, muchas gracias, lo aumente a 512 y ahora por lo menos funciona mucho mejor y no se cuelga.

Comment: Que bien que te funciono. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Verifique que su página esté siendo procesada por PHP - pregunta obvia, pero ¿tiene su archivo PHP una extensión .php? Haga otras cosas como phpinfo () o echo "Test"; ¿trabajo?

Verifique el registro de errores en /var/log/apache2/error.log o similar (si está en Linux, no sé dónde estaría en Windows).

Intente activar display_errors en la configuración de PHP (esta es una buena idea solo para una instalación de desarrollo, no para un servidor de producción).

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]. Ademas de todo eso, porque hacer wiki una respuesta que no es respuesta?